# Is Sodium hydroxide good for cleaning mould?

Tags: bathroom

I have heard that using sodium hydroxide is good for getting rid of mould. I get mould on my artex ceiling even though I ventilate and use a dehumidifier. Will it damage the artex or can anyone suggest something better.

Comment: As with most putting stuff on something, try it on a small hopefully hidden area first.  Bleach is also good and probably safer than lye.  I think hydrogen peroxide is good also.   Wear eye protection with whatever you use.

Comment: Sodium hydroxide is lye. Lye is extremely hazardous unless you take appropriate precautions. Applying it to a ceiling seems like a good way to potentially lose an eye, unless you are very, very careful.

Comment: If you ventilate and dehumidify and still get mold I'd suggest that you have a leak which needs addressing.

Comment: Start with a commercial mold remover before using NaOH in a concentration that dissolves your skin.

Comment: Just reiterating TigerGuy's and Ecnerwal's caustic comments!

Comment: You could use *both* eyes applying lye above your head. Lye is not the go to chemical to deal with mold. There are "mildewcides" which will attack mold and be much safer. Even with those you should wear appropriate eye protection.

Comment: Anyone who tells you to use sodium hydroxide for cleaning mold is lyeing.

Answer (score 2):

The comments warn you not to use sodium hydroxide for mold on your ceiling because sodium hydroxide is the chemical name for lye, which can blind you if you get it in your eyes.

But consider that you may have mis-read or mis-heard what's good for mold.

**Sodium hypochlorite** (which sounds a little like hydroxide I suppose) is good for mold on hard, non-porous surfaces. That's the chemical name for one form of chlorine bleach, the other being calcium hypochlorite.

Neither hypochlorite is suitable for use on painted surfaces, nor on a ceiling, as they can drip in your eyes too, and potentially injure your eyes.

Shop for a mold and mildew cleaner that is suitable for use on painted surfaces and read the precautions on the label before use.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of 5% sodium hypochlorite solution, aka household bleach. Bleach is the cheapest, safest, and most effective way to remove mold from house surfaces. Just look at the list of ingredients on any mold cleaner, and it will say "sodium hypochlorite". They are just repackaged bleach.

Start by diluting a few mL on a Liter of water, and spray on the ceiling. Wait a few minutes and then wipe it off with wet towel.